# Can Ruby be avoided when creating Android application using Eclipse in Windows environment?

Tags: android, ruby, eclipse, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-7

We are about to develop an web application using **ASP.NET MVC4** and an android application in which we will use **Phonegap**. Those two applications will be connected with each other. We found out that **Ruby** is a  prerequisite  **Windows environment**. Is it true that **Ruby** cannot be avoided? Please help.

Comment: where did you find that out? I'm not aware of any such connection?

Comment: What connection are you talking about @Nanne?

Comment: the one from your question. The one between Ruby and.. well.. everything else :)

Comment: Checkout this: 


http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/16494774/Getting%20started%20with%20Android%20PhoneGap%20in%20Eclipse

Comment: Ah. As far as I can see, Ruby is used to create an example app. If you don't need to create an example app, I see no need for it :)

Comment: Got it. But my question got downgraded. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has nothing to do with android development on windows using Phonegap. Here's a setup guide for phonegap on a Mac:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

You don't need Ruby at any stage for Android in Windows or Mac.

Here's the official getting started guide which covers both windows and mac set-ups:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Comment: Okay. I checked it just now but that tutorial is based on iOS. Would it work for Windows 7 too?

Comment: Yes, of course! I was about to but the 6 mins rule stopped me.

Comment: can you provide me an alternative tutorial which is based on windows? It would be very much appreciated.